# Meaning of the map function in couchdb-pythons ViewField

Tags: python, couchdb, couchdb-python

I'm using the [couchdb.mapping](http://packages.python.org/CouchDB/mapping.html) in one of my projects. I have a class called `SupportCase` derived from `Document` that contains all the fields I want.

My database (called `admin`) contains multiple document types. I have a `type` field in all the documents which I use to distinguish between them. I have many documents of type `"case"` which I want to get at using a view. I have design document called `support` with a view inside it called `cases`. If I request the results of this view using `db.view("support/cases)`, I get back a list of `Row`s which have what I want.

However, I want to somehow have this wrapped by the `SupportCase` class so that I can call a single function and get back a list of all the `SupportCase`s in the system. I created a `ViewField` property

```
@ViewField.define('cases')
def all(self, doc):
    if doc.get("type","") == "case":
        yield doc["_id"], doc
```

Now, if I call `SupportCase.all(db)`, I get back all the cases.

What I don't understand is whether this view is precomputed and stored in the database or done on demand similar to `db.query`. If it's the latter, it's going to be slow and I want to use a precomputed view. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think what you need is:

```
@classmethod
def all(cls):
    result = cls.view(db, "support/all", include_docs=True)
    return result.rows
```

`Document` class has a classmethod `view` which wraps the rows by class on which it is called. So the following returns you a `ViewResult` with rows of type `SupportCase` and taking `.rows` of that gives a list of support cases.

```
SupportCase.view(db, viewname, include_docs=True)
```

And I don't think you need to get into the ViewField magic. But let me explain how it works. Consider the following example from the `CouchDB-python` documentation.

```
class Person(Document):
     @ViewField.define('people')
     def by_name(doc):
         yield doc['name'], doc
```

I think this is equivalent to:

```
class Person(Document):
    @classmethod
    def by_name(cls, db, **kw):
        return cls.view(db, **kw)
```

With the original function attached to `People.by_name.map_fun`.

Comment: This works. I should have asked you first before posting on SO. :)

Answer (score 0):

The map function is in some ways analogous to an index in a relational database.  It is not done again every time, and when new documents are added the way it is updated does not require everything to be redone (it's a kind of tree structure).

This has a pretty good [summary](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/views.html)

Comment: I know what it is and how it is maintained. The design document should contain the map and reduce functions and it's computed incrementally. If that's the case, then what is the function definition shown above doing? That's in the code. It should be in the database (unless it's a temporary view). In other words, I'm particularly interested in how the coucdhb-python library works rather than couch itself.

Comment: If you are just wanting to get the results of the view, which is what it sounds like you want, then your use of db.view("_design/myapp/_view") is better.  I personally don't have a problem with creating/defining the view in couchdb, perhaps using futon, and then just accessing the results in python.  If you are for some reason wanting all the code to be in python, then you can use the above code to do the definition in python.  But I would recommend just defining the view in couch directly and only pulling back results in python.  Is there a reason db.view isn't acceptable for your purposes?

Comment: I want the results to get automatically wrapped as `SupportCase` objects (I don't have a reduce function) so that I can manipulate them directly.

Comment: Can't you call db.view inside SupportCase, so that the instantiation of SupportCase is calling on pre-made views?

Comment: I *could* but I want to know what `ViewField` does.

Answer (score 0):

ViewField uses a pre-defined view so, once built, will be fast. It definitely doesn't use a temporary view.

Comment: Well, this fact is useless to me unless I can specify which design document it should use. I don't want to put the map/reduce functions in my application code. All I really want is to say something like `SupportCase.all(db)` and it should return all the cases wrapped with the `SupportCase` `Document` class.

Comment: I actually agree, and I hope to change CouchDB to handle this better. However, you did ask specifically about whether a ViewField uses a precomputed view or db.query.

Comment: True. The question is a mix of frustration, genuine curiosity and a brain dump. :)